Como faço para sobrepor gráficos? R - Software
No software R, consigo gerar estes gráficos através do ggplot, portanto quero sobrepor um gráfico no outro, isto é possível?
Como faço para sobrepor estes dois gráficos iguais, mas de diferentes setores?
Primeira parte do código
#chamar os pacotes da biblioteca
library( "aqui pacotes" )
dados_brutos <- read.xlsx("C:/dados.xlsx",
sheetIndex = 1,
as.data.frame = T,
header = T)
X = data.frame(VL = dados_brutos$VALUE,
PW = dados_brutos$POWER,
SI = dados_brutos$STRATEGIC.IMPORTANCE)
X = scale(X)
set.seed(1)
kmeans = kmeans(x = X, centers = 4)
clusters = kmeans$cluster
primeiro setor seria este de energia
#dados_energy

ggplot(dados_energy, aes(x=POWER, y=STRATEGIC.IMPORTANCE)) + geom_point(aes(col = clusters)) + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) + theme_bw()

segundo setor seria este de vida
#dados_life

ggplot(dados_life, aes(x=POWER, y=STRATEGIC.IMPORTANCE)) + geom_point(aes(col = clusters)) + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) + theme_bw()

Com estes gráficos gerados, tem uma análise cada um, portanto queria sobrepor estas análises, teria alguma forma de sobrepor?

Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada neste link (principalmente no uso da função dput) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Não duplique perguntas. Os comentários foram bloqueados para que continue na pergunta original.
